# Why won't my R app deploy to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am new to R and shiny and was trying to publish a small app using gapminder data.  The app works fine locally, but errors out when going to publish to shinyapps.io.  Initially, I thought that it wasn't grabbing the data from the library and moved it to a csv in the directory, but this didn't do anything.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:  There is another message box that says the layout is invalid, but lets me continue anyways.

```
#test data to play with
#library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
gapminder <- read.csv("gapminder_data.csv")

gapminder$country <- factor(gapminder$country)


#actual shiny work
library(shiny)

# Define User Inerface for application
#themes, objects and features are put here
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(

  sidebarPanel(

    h4("Plot parameters"),
    textInput("title", "Plot Title", "Life Expectancy Over Time"),
    numericInput("num", "Number of years to show", 30, 1, nrow(gapminder)),
    sliderInput("size", "Point size", 1, 5, 2, 0.5),
    selectInput("country", "Select a country", choices=levels(factor(gapminder$country)),selected="Togo")
  ),

  mainPanel(

    plotOutput("plot"),
    tableOutput("table")

  )
))

# function that will output results to the html page
server <- function(input, output) {

  df_out <- reactive(subset(gapminder,country==input$country))

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(x=df_out()$year[1:input$num],y=df_out()$lifeExp[1:input$num], main = input$title, cex = input$size)
  })
}

  #output$table <- renderTable({})

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

> Session information:  R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) Platform:
>   x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build
>   18362)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  [2]
>   LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United
>   States.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           [5]
>   LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_3.6.1
>   rsconnect_0.8.15 Cookies:  [1] "None" GET
>   /v1/applications/?filter=account_id:379483&filter=name:shiny_notes&count=100&offset=0
>   199ms
>   ----- Bundle upload started at  2019-12-01 23:07:13  ----- [2019-12-01 23:07:13] Inferring App mode and parameters 
>   ----- Deployment error ----- Error in inferAppPrimaryDoc(appPrimaryDoc = appPrimaryDoc, appFiles = appFiles,  :    Application mode static requires at least one document. Calls:  ... withStatus ->
>   force -> bundleApp -> inferAppPrimaryDoc

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack Overflow. How yo are uploading the csv file??I think its in your local system right??

Comment: I tried using just the library and then I put the app in it's own folder with the csv.  I ticked the two checkboxes to publish the app and the csv.  If you comment out read.csv and just use library I get the same problem.

Comment: I got it to work, but I'm not sure why.  Initially I was using the publish button on the window that appeared when running the app locally.  When I ran it using the publish button in the coding window, it worked fine.  Does anyone know why it acted this way?